# Include the company's URL in Stack Overflow careers PDF resume

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story, cv-export

I noticed that when I export my Stack Overflow careers resume as PDF, I cannot see the URLs of the companies I worked for.

All of the companies I worked at are small local companies unknown outside my country. I think if I send it to a recruiter abroad, he/she will not bother looking into the companies I worked at, he/she might think I'm bluffing and dismiss the resume.

It would be nice to display the company's URL in the PDF version of the resume, just to make it easier for the recruiter to check the company out.

Comment: LinkedIn has the same problem too, I'll let them know, hopefully they solve it

Comment: LinkedIn replied saying that they will only  fix the issue if many users report it. If you could report it there as well, it would be awesome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Company names now appear as links in the PDF if a company website has been provided in the dev story editor:

[image]

=>

[image]

Comment: awh, you missed the opportunity to go for `https://foo.bar/foobar` as website D: